# Discrepancy when using Saha equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

I was trying to calculate the level of ionization using Saha eq. for hydrogen gas at 1 atm pressure at 10 000 K and upwards. I used an Excel spreadsheet and the values I get don't match with other sources on the web.

I get 50% ionization at 24 000 K but this other source gives a far lower value; approx. 15 000 K. Why?

The other source is:

http://www.wag.caltech.edu/home/jsu/Thesis/node31.html

[image]

I used the equation in the following pdf file and simply plugged in a higher density:

http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~townsend/resource/teaching/astro-310-F09/hydrogen-ionization.pdf

[image]